# TikZ: Removing the inner line of circle split, rectangle split, etc.

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you remove the line of the split within a split shape (like circle split or rectangle split). For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle split, thick]{$1$ \nodepart{lower} $2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives you a thick circle with a thick splitting line. Can the middle line be removed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to use a greeting in your posts. You can format code in your posts by starting the line with four spaces, or by selecting the code and pressing the `10101` button in the editor.

Answer (score 4):

This answer was given to me by Mark Wibrow (thank you Mark!). I'm quoting it here for future reference:

If you just want to eliminate the `split` line then try using the `rectangle split draw splits key`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3}]
\node {text \nodepart{second} \nodepart{third}third};
\node [rectangle split ignore empty parts] at (2,0)
{text \nodepart{second} \nodepart{third}third};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3, rectangle split draw splits=false}]
\node {text \nodepart{second} \nodepart{third}third};
\node [rectangle split ignore empty parts] at (2,0)
{text \nodepart{second} \nodepart{third}third};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this does unfortunately not work analogously for circle nodes. is there any key for that?

Comment: @IARI [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.